# Comparing Two Matrices in MATLAB which shows how much they are matched

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, comparison

Please assume `A` is a matrix of `4 x 4` which has:

```
A =  1     0     1     0
     1     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0
     1     1     0     0
```

And `B` is a reference matrix (`4 x 4`) which is:

```
B =  1     0     1     0
     1     0     1     0
     1     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0
```

Now, if `A` would be compared to `B` which is the reference matrix, by matching these two matrices, almost all of members are equal except `A(4,3)` and `A(3,2)`. However, since `B` is the reference matrix and `A` is comparing to that, only differences of those members are matter which are `1` in `B`. In this particular example, `A(4,3)` is only matter, not `A(3,2)`, Means:

`>> C = B ~= A;
ans =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0`

`A(4,3) ~= B(4,3)`

Finally, we are looking for a piece of code which can show how many percentage of ones in `A` are equal to their equivalent members at `B`. In this case the difference is:

`(8 / 9) * 100 = 88.89 %` are matched.

Please bear in mind that speed is also important here. Therefore, quicker solution are more appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Who is `we`? Is that a group homework? First show what have you tried so far.

Comment: In your question it's not clear, if the percentage is a percentage relative to ones in `A` or `B`. I assumed that it is a percentage of the reference-matrix, which is `B`. Therefore I divide by `sum(B(:))`. Could you clarify this, so I can change my code if needed?

Comment: @Matt Thanks a lot. You're grants. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting only the different entries where there is a `1` in `B`, just add an `&` to it, so you'll only get these entries. To get the percentage, take the `sum` where `A` and `B` are `1`. Then divide it by the sum of `1` in `B` (or the sum of `1`in `A` -> *see the note below*).

```
A = [1 0 1 0;
     1 0 1 0;
     1 1 1 0;
     1 1 0 0];

B = [1 0 1 0;
     1 0 1 0;
     1 0 1 0;
     1 1 1 0];

C = (B ~= A) & B

p = sum(B(:) & A(:)) / sum(B(:)) * 100
```

*This is the result:*

```
C =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0
p =
   88.8889
```

---

**Edit / Note:** In the OP's question it's not 100% clear if he wants the percentage in relation to the sum of ones in `A` or `B`. I assumed that it is a percentage of the reference-matrix, which is `B`. Therefore I divide by `sum(B(:))`. In case you need it in reference to the ones in `A`, just change the last line to:

```
p = sum(B(:) & A(:)) / sum(A(:)) * 100
```

Comment: On the percentage formula, dividing by `sum(B(:))` is wrong. The OP wants to know the percentage of `ones in A`, so the universe is `A`. You should divide by `sum(A(:))` (look at my answer).

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro As I understood, he wants to know the percentage of matching ones in `A` in relation to the reference-matrix `B`. But he was not 100% explicit and the example can be ambiguous. I left a comment on his question, so he can clarify this.

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro: As the OP states in a comment on his question that my answer with `sum(B(:))` is correct. Anyways, I still added a note to cover both cases as I admit it's confusing.

Comment: @jucestain: As the OP states in a comment on his question that my answer with `sum(B(:))` is correct. Anyways, I still added a note to cover both cases as I admit it's confusing.

Comment: @Matt *piece of code which can show how many percentage of ones in `A` are equal to their equivalent members at `B`*. That's pretty clear that it's the percentage with respect to A, but if he says you're right then the question is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right, what you want to know is where `B == 1` and `A == 0`.
Try this:

```
>> C = B & ~A

C =

     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0
```

To get the percentage, you could try this:

```
>> 100 * sum(A(:) & B(:)) / sum(A(:))
ans =

    88.8889
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use matrix-multiplication, which must be pretty efficient as listed next.

To get the percentage value with respect to `A` -

```
percentage_wrtA = A(:).'*B(:)/sum(A(:)) * 100;
```

To get the percentage value with respect to `B` -

```
percentage_wrtB = A(:).'*B(:)/sum(B(:)) * 100;
```

---

**Runtime tests**

Here's some quick runtime tests to compare matrix-multiplication against summation of elements with `(:)` and `ANDing` -

```
>> M = 6000;  %// Datasize
>> A = randi([0,1],M,M);
>> B = randi([0,1],M,M);
>> tic,sum(B(:) & A(:));toc
Elapsed time is 0.500149 seconds.
>> tic,A(:).'*B(:);toc
Elapsed time is 0.126881 seconds.
```

Comment: your approach is quicker and more clear in general. Good job!

However, I don't know whether I should choose your answer as a final solution or the other one, as he was first. 

Again, thanks a lot for your time. I use yours in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sum(sum(A & B))./sum(sum(A))
```

Output:

```
ans =

    0.8889
```

Comment: OP wants only when B is non zero.